# DIY SLA 3d printer for jewelry

Tags: sla

Where i can find DIY-project or tutorial for creating SLA printer for making models of jewelry?

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for this site, as it calls for link-only answers.  Such answers would inevitably become outdated and obsolete as the linked resource disappears or changes, and summarizing the content of the linked source is impossible given the large scope of the question.

Comment: Hmm. I make wrong question. "Prease, give me a link to the good DIY-manual for creating SLA 3d printer."

Comment: I have no experience with that directly, but may I humbly suggest googling "diy sla printer" as a starting point?  I did, and the quick search yielded lots of interesting reading.  Good luck.  :-)

Comment: Hi, Alexandr! As pointed out by Tom, your question is not a good fit for this site. Please take a look at our [help section](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help) for an introduction to 3D Printer Stack Exchange.